# Doubt about whether repunits are square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers, repunit-numbers

I have doubts in this exercise.

> - Can a number $A= 111...11$, ($1000$ times the number $1$), be a square?
> - Can a number $B= 111...11$, ($10431$ times the number $1$), be a square?
> - Can a number $C= 111...11$, ($n$ times the number $1$), be a square?

I thought that if the number ends in $1$ it is odd, so I can write it in the form $A = 2k + 1$.

But in this way, I always find that it is not a square, regardless of the number of times that the number $1$ appears.

Is it okay to think the way I'm thinking?

Thanks.

Comment: An odd number can be a square... $3^2 = 9$.

Comment: A square cannot leave remainder $3$ when divided by $4$

Comment: To show a natural number is not square, it suffices to exhibit a (prime) factor whose multiplicity is odd.

Comment: Alternatively to J.W. Tanner's comment, a square cannot end in ...11.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298234/prove-that-none-of-11-111-1111-dots-is-the-perfect-square-of-an-intege) is a duplicate involving all $1$s, not $9$s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comments, a square cannot be $3\pmod{4}.$ (See the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571402/there-is-no-square-number-that-is-3-mod-4).)

Also note that all the numbers in a), b), and c) end in $11$ and therefore are $3\pmod{4}.$ (Divisibility rule by 4 is to find if the last two digits are divisible by 4, if they are, then the entire number is.)

Therefore, any number of just $1$s other than $1$ cannot be a perfect square.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

An odd number can be a square; for example $121=11^2$.

But if you try squaring even ($2k$) and odd ($2k+1$) numbers, you will see that squares must leave remainder $0$ or $1$ when divided by $4$.

The remainder when a number is divided by $4$ is the same as the remainder when the number comprising its last two digits is divided by $4$.

Therefore, the remainder when the repunit number $111\dots11$ is divided by $4$ is the same as the remainder when $11$ is divided by $4$, which is $3$, so $111\dots11$ cannot be a square.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand.